# Build js library by webpack with typescript defenitions

Tags: typescript

For example, I have library that contains 2 files written in commonjs.

---

`button.js` with typings `button.d.ts`:

```
class Button {};

export = Button;
```

---

`index.js` with typings `index.d.ts`:

```
import Button = require("./button");

export var myButton: typeof Button;
```

---

I want to generate `mylib.d.ts` that can be used by global namespace. Like this:

```
let button = new MyLib.Button();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although typescript supports global type declarations, you'll still have to import the actual implementation of the class:

```
// index.d.ts
declare namespace MyLib {
  class Button {
    public name
    constructor(name: string)
  }
}

// index.ts

class theButton {
  public count
  public name
  constructor(count: number) {
    this.count = count
  }
}

let a: MyLib.Button = new theButton(1)
a.name // compiles fine
a.count // compilation error
```